# SQL Server : please confirm if my query provides correct results

Tags: sql-server

I want to show which orders contain more than two products?

Show order number, order value, and number of products that the order contains.

FYI I added the 2 extra columns because the result would look better.

```
WITH RESULTS AS
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        COUNT(O2.SalesOrderID) OVER (PARTITION BY O2.SalesOrderID) AS COUNTS 
    FROM 
        AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS O2
    --  WHERE COUNTS > 1
    --  ORDER BY SalesOrderID ASC
)
SELECT 
    O.SalesOrderID,
    p.Name, P.ProductID, R.COUNTS as [Products Amount],
    R.LineTotal, R.OrderQty
FROM 
    RESULTS AS R
INNER JOIN 
    AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS O ON R.SalesOrderID = O.SalesOrderID
RIGHT JOIN 
    AdventureWorks2014.Production.Product as P ON P.ProductID = R.ProductID
WHERE
    R.COUNTS > 1
ORDER BY 
    O.SalesOrderID ASC
```

[CLICK HERE TO SEE THE NEW IMAGE PLEASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSNnd.jpg)

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: SQL Server returns the correct result for the data and query. If it returns something unexpected, it is a problem with the query and/or data assumptions. There is nothing to ‘confirm’ on SO.

Comment: Hi guys, I have added an image to the query which shows the problems when I add joins

Comment: I got it right, i moved the joins to the RESULTS query which includes counts, then put a where clause on COUNTS and job done

Answer (score 0):

I got it right, i moved the joins to the RESULTS query which includes counts, then put a where clause on COUNTS and job done

```
    WITH RESULTS AS
(
    SELECT O2.SalesOrderID
        ,O2.ProductID
        ,P.Name AS [Product Name]
        ,O2.UnitPrice
        ,O2.OrderQty
        ,O2.LineTotal
        ,COUNT(O2.SalesOrderID)OVER(PARTITION BY O2.SalesOrderID)  AS COUNTS 
    FROM AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS O2
    INNER JOIN AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS H ON O2.SalesOrderID = H.SalesOrderID
    INNER JOIN AdventureWorks2014.Production.Product as P ON P.ProductID = O2.ProductID
)

SELECT R.SalesOrderID
    ,R.[Product Name]
    ,R.ProductID
    ,R.COUNTS AS [Products Amount Per Order]
    ,R.OrderQty
    ,R.UnitPrice
    ,R.LineTotal AS [Total Payment Per Order]

FROM RESULTS AS R
WHERE R.COUNTS > 1
ORDER BY SalesOrderID ASC
```